# Read input line by line

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

How do I read input line by line in Java? I searched and so far I have this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MatrixReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (input.hasNext()) {
            System.out.print(input.nextLine());
        }
    }
```

The problem with this is that it doesn't read the last line. So if I input

```
 10 5 4 20
 11 6 55 3
 9 33 27 16
```

its output will only be

```
10 5 4 20 11 6 55 3
```

Comment: Works fine for me using your exact code.  Don't forget to press enter.

Comment: Why not `Scanner.hasNextLine`?

Comment: I think you  have copied than pasted all input variable at once

Comment: Lol, I did't press enter. I feel dumb now.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Ideally you should add a final println() because by default System.out uses a PrintStream that only flushes when a newline is sent. See [When/why to call System.out.flush() in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7166328/when-why-to-call-system-out-flush-in-java)

```
while (input.hasNext()) {
    System.out.print(input.nextLine());
}
System.out.println();
```

Although there are possible other reasons for your issue.

Comment: how the hell does this answer answer the question??

Comment: @Bohdan the answer is in the comments under the question. The OP just forgot to press enter after the last line, so it was not processed by the program. I guess he just accepted the most-upvoted answer after he realised he was "dumb" (his words not mine) for not pressing enter

Answer (score 7):

The previously posted suggestions have typo (hasNextLine spelling) and new line printing (println needed each line) issues.  Below is the corrected version --

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class XXXX {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (input.hasNextLine()){
            System.out.println(input.nextLine());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `hasnextLine()` method.

```
while (input.hasnextLine()){


    System.out.print(input.nextLine());


 }
```