# Remove a certain character from a .txt file

Tags: java, spaces

If I type

```
java DeleteX e < input.txt > output.txt
```

in the terminal, the code is supposed to remove a certain character (in this case `e`) from the `input.txt` file and then save the same text to a new file `output.txt` but all the `e`s should be removed.

Ex: If the text in `input.txt` is as follows:

```
Hello! My name is John Doe.
```

The `output.txt` file should be:

```
Hllo! My nam is John Do.
```

But I don't get the spaces in `output.txt`. I get:

```
Hllo!MynamisJohnDo.
```

Code:

```
public class DeleteX{
public static void main(String []args){

String x = args[0]; // The character I want removed from the text
char X = x.charAt(0); // Transform the character from String to char

    while(! StdIn.isEmpty()){
        String line = StdIn.readString(); // The .txt file

        for( int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++){


            if( line.charAt(i) != X ){
                System.out.print(line.charAt(i));

            } // if             
        } // for
     } // while 
   } // main
} // class
```

Comment: You never write in an Output file in your code

Comment: where you're trying to read and write data into text file in your code?

Comment: The command line is using redirection, @Jens and Omore.

Comment: it seems that you forgot to write to output.txt file

Comment: it is removing both `e` and space or just spaces?

Comment: Have you used a Debugger, to fins out what is happend?

Comment: @javafan Take a look at the command line. Any printed output will go to `output.txt`.

Comment: What does `StdIn.readString()` do? It's not part of the JRE. Are you sure it reads a line at a time?

Comment: We don't know what your `StdIn` class does. My guess is that `readString` reads the next string up to the next space. In which case, of course, it will not read the space itself.

Comment: I agree, the problem is in `readString` since rest of the code works fine http://ideone.com/Uc2X03

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ -- specifically the thing to do here is to either to debug by putting a `println(line)` following `line = StdIn.readString()`, or (better) to step through execution with a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I think a better way to do this is to use the `replace` method on the string.

like:

```
line = line.replace(x, "");
```

and then just print that out.

Comment: What if `x` is `.` ?

Comment: what difference does that make?

Comment: Oops, actually the problem with yours is that it only replaces the first instance of `x`. So you might want `replaceAll()` -- but the first argument to `replaceAll(String,String)` is a regular expression.

Comment: I just tried an example to make sure, and `replace` does replaces all occurences of `x` from the string.

Comment: My mistake - apologies.

Answer (score 0):

you can use String.replace method to replace the character. 
e.g.

```
String replaceString=s1.replaceAll(""+x,""); //replaces all occurrences of x to "".
```

e.g.

```
String input = "Hello! My name is John Doe.";
char X = 'e';
System.out.println(input.replaceAll("" + X, ""));
```

The output printed is - `Hllo! My nam is John Do.`

Comment: What is an "empty char"?

Comment: There is no "empty char"... `''`won't compile. You need `String#replace(String, String)` with `""` as second parameter

Comment: I agree that it's easier to use the library implementation of replace than to write your own loop - but if OP uses this approach, they'll get the same result they already do, since their input string will still be missing spaces.

Comment: what if occurrence of x is more than one in given string?

Comment: @slim str.trim() is also useful in this case.

Comment: As @MushabarAbbas points out above, `replace(String,String)` *does* replace all instances. Reverted my edit.

Comment: thanks @slim. Not sure why the answer was down voted then

Comment: @vlaxmi it doesn't actually solve the OP's problem; put `line.replace(...)` into their program instead of the loop, and it would still give a result with no spaces.

Comment: @slim - For this code the result is as expected - String input = "Hello! My name is John Doe.";
char X = 'e';
System.out.println(input.replaceAll("" + X, "")); this gives expected result.

Comment: why was it down voted? the answer is correct as updated on above comment. Also attached output to the answer

Comment: @vlaximi this isn't OP's problem. If `line == "Hello! My name is John Doe."` OP's loop would write `"Hllo! My nam is John Do."`. OP's problem is (probably) that `line` is `"Hello!"` then `"My"`, `"name"` etc.  There is nothing wrong with OP's char-stripping loop, except that it could be replaced with a library method. But OP doesn't seem interested in following up, so this page is effectively dead.

Answer (score 0):

According to this page  http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/javadoc/StdIn.html

the StdIn functions operate by reading tokens one at a time, where

> A token is a maximal sequence of non-whitespace characters.

That means your call to StdIn.readString(); is not reading a line at a time, but a token (or word) at a time - by definition, without spaces.

So you should read a line at a time instead, instead of using StdIn.  See [Read input line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11842091/read-input-line-by-line)

Comment: You're probably right, but it's a bit of a guess whether this is the `StdIn` class OP is using.