# why we use system.out.flush()?

Tags: java, system.out

Can someone please explain why we we would use `system.out.flush()` in a simpler way? If there could be a chance of losing data, please provide me with an example. If you comment it in the code below nothing changes!

```
class ReverseApp{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    String input, output;
    while(true){

        System.out.print("Enter a string: ");
        System.out.flush();
        input = getString(); // read a string from kbd
        if( input.equals("") ) // quit if [Enter]
        break;
        // make a Reverser
        Reverser theReverser = new Reverser(input);
        output = theReverser.doRev(); // use it
        System.out.println("Reversed: " + output);

   }
   }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Some methods of `PrintStream` do not `flush` by default.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7166328/when-why-to-call-system-out-flush-in-java

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> When you write data out to a stream, some amount of buffering will occur, and you never know for sure exactly when the last of the data will actually be sent. You might perform many
>   operations on a stream before closing it, and invoking the flush() method guarantees that the last of the data you thought you had already written actually gets out to the file.

Extract from [Sun Certified Programmer for Java 6 Exam by Sierra & Bates](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071591060).

In your example, it doesn't change anything because `System.out` performs auto-flushing meaning that everytime a byte in written in the buffer, it is automatically flushed.

Comment: Not on all platforms. On most it's flushed on a (platform-dependent) newline.

Answer (score 3):

You use System.out.flush() to write any data stored in the out buffer. Buffers store text up to a point and then write when full. If you terminate a program without flushing a buffer, you could potentially lose data.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what the say [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/OutputStream.html#flush%28%29).