# Strange behaviour of write method

Tags: java

I was looking some methods of PrintStream class and came across [write()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#write%28int%29) and as per the docs to print in the console we need to call `System.out.flush();`.But my doubt is if I write these lines

```
System.out.write(40);
System.out.write(10);
```

Then also `(` gets printed.I know `10` represents **new line** but I wanted to know why it only happens with new line.If I write

```
 System.out.write(40);
 System.out.write(32); 32 for space then also nothing gets printed.
```

[Demonstration](http://ideone.com/7eSQ3f)

Comment: The answers below have covered it but this answer gives some additional related information: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7166357/3025921

Comment: You have linked the documentation, which itself contains the answer: *`If the byte is a newline and automatic flushing is enabled then the flush method will be invoked.`* I am not sure why you are asking this question.

Comment: @Sage Because my own expected behavior would be that while `System.out` might not get dumped to stdout for a while, surely any remaining output would get printed when the program exits.

Comment: @chrylis, yes i understand. But as soon as we look into the implementation details our expectations become justified. In fact i also wanted to answer the question, but i re-read and clicked on the documentation OP himself linked: i just stunned to see that the answer is already there and got confused what really he is after! If he asked that he wants something like clarification then i would not bother but answer it. Please, don't get me wrong :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the `PrintStream.write`:

```
if ((b == '\n') && autoFlush)
   out.flush();
}
```

So if you write a new-line to a `System.out` it will be auto-flushed.
Btw javadoc says that too:

> Writes the specified byte to this stream. If the byte is a newline and automatic flushing is enabled then the flush method will be invoked.

Comment: @JqueryLearner in this case when you call `println` it will call `newLine` which in turn will call `flush`.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the output stream is line-buffered - that is, it automatically flushes when it sees an end-of-line. To guarantee your ouput you should always use flush().

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a race condition in `PrintStream`. [The (OpenJDK 6) `PrintStream` code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/PrintStream.java#PrintStream.write%28int%29) forces a flush of the underlying `OutputStream` whenever the output written includes the character `\n`, but not any other time, and there's no sort of finalizer that ensures that buffered output in the `BufferedOutputStream` the JVM wraps around standard output gets flushed when the JVM exits.

[The code that initializes the `System` class](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/System.java#System.initializeSystemClass%28%29) uses a 128-byte buffer for `System.out`, and if you output enough characters to fill the buffer (I inserted a 128-count `for` loop around writing the `(` character), you'll see the output on the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#write%28int%29).

```
public void write(int b)

Writes the specified byte to this stream. If the byte is a newline and automatic 
flushing is enabled then the flush method will be invoked.
```

Comment: Though denies answer is more appropriate but yours also useful for future users,+1