# Java Thread.sleep inquiry

Tags: java

So I was wondering if there was anyway I could implement this code so that it pauses on each loop iteration. Currently, when I run the code, the program will stop for n seconds (n being the amount of loop iterations) and then display everything at once. However, I wish for it to display one item, wait one second and display the next item. I hope this is clear.

```
while(x > 0 || y > 0){
        Try{
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Print x and y
        //Change x and y vals

        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you asking how to flush stdout? If so, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7166328/when-why-to-call-system-out-flush-in-java

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion: separate the thread sleep in a method to do the job without rewriting all this code.

Suggestion 2: search aroung if thread sleep is the best solution for you

Try this:

```
    public void waitSeconds(int seconds){
       try{ 
           Thread.sleep(seconds*1000l); 
       } catch(Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace(); //ugly but enough to explain
       };
    }
    public void yourMethod(){
        while(x > 0 || y > 0){
            waitSeconds(1);
            print x
            waitSeconds(1);
            print y
            //Change x and y vals    
            }
    }
```

Comment: You should never suppress `InterruptedException`.

Comment: The edit still suppresses the exception, it's just noisier.  If the thread is interrupted, you should propagate the interruption, not suppress it.

Answer (score 0):

First, [don't suppress `InterruptedException`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3976377/113632).  If there's nothing to be done about it, simply don't catch it at all, or convert it into a `RuntimeException` e.g.

```
throw new RuntimeException(ie);
```

Second, it sounds like you're describing a [flushing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7166328/113632) problem, which can be addressed by adding calls to:

```
System.out.flush();
```

After you print your values.  As mentioned in the linked question however, `System.out` and `System.err` auto-flush whenever a new line is printed; are you not printing to stdout, or not printing new lines?

You should have a `Thread.sleep()` call wherever you need the program to pause, so if you need to pause between printing `x` and `y`, add another `Thread.sleep()` between them.

Answer (score -1):

It's really strange. Try this way:

```
while(x > 0 || y > 0) {
    // Print old values
    // Change your x and y
    // Print new values

    try {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(y);
    } catch(InterruptedException ex) {}
}
```

Comment: You should not suppress `InterruptedException`.  Additionally, `TimeUnit.sleep()` calls `Thread.sleep()`, so this is no help.