# webstrom2017 conosle.log '123\r123'

Tags: javascript, console.log

when I use webStrom2017 to console.log('123\r123'), it results in '123'. And I find if there are characters before and after \r. It will only output the following characters. Is this a BUG?

Comment: Good point. There seems to be a bug in webStorm for `\r`. See the answers to the question asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39798849/4636715

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not a bug. Basically, `\r` means return cursor to the start of the row. That's why in windows to go to the new line you need `\r\n`,  which means "go to start of the row, go to next row". This is the legacy of old computers with no UI.

So, when you print to terminal `123\r123` it means "write `123`, go to start of the row and *overwrite* with 123".

However, nowadays, you can use either `\n` or `\r\n` in both UNIX-like OSes and windows.