# System.out.print output to console seen immediately. So PrintStream flushes after each print, not only println?

Tags: java, printstream, autoflush

From the PrintStream [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#PrintStream(java.io.OutputStream)):

> Optionally, a PrintStream can be created so as to flush automatically;
>   this means that the *flush method is automatically invoked* after a **byte
>   array is written**, one of the **println methods is invoked**, or a **newline
>   character or byte ('\n') is written**.

Then given code

```
System.out.print("hi");   // gives console output: hi
System.out.print(7);      // gives console output: 7

// prevents flushing when stream wiil be closed at app shutdown
for (;;) {
}
```

**Why then I see output to my console?  Nothing shall be written to console** (PrintStream instance from System.out), **because nothing shall be flushed so far!**

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7166328/when-why-to-call-system-out-flush-in-java) didn't answer this.

I guess, the answer is in the source code (private utility method BufferedWriter.flushBuffer()), but I don't understand the comment to code: "Flushes the output buffer to the underlying character stream, *without flushing the stream itself*": if PrintStream (which is tied to console output), which is "stream itself" is not flushed, output to console shall not be refreshed!...

Source for PrintStream.print(String):

```
private void write(String s) {
        try {
            synchronized (this) {
                ensureOpen();
                textOut.write(s);
                textOut.flushBuffer();
                charOut.flushBuffer();
                if (autoFlush && (s.indexOf('\n') >= 0))
                    out.flush();
            }
        }
        catch (InterruptedIOException x) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
        catch (IOException x) {
            trouble = true;
        }
    }
```

Source for BufferedWriter.flushBuffer():

```
/**
     * Flushes the output buffer to the underlying character stream, without
     * flushing the stream itself.  This method is non-private only so that it
     * may be invoked by PrintStream.
     */
    void flushBuffer() throws IOException {
        synchronized (lock) {
            ensureOpen();
            if (nextChar == 0)
                return;
            out.write(cb, 0, nextChar);
            nextChar = 0;
        }
    }
```

More details are also given [here](https://luckytoilet.wordpress.com/2010/05/21/how-system-out-println-really-works/). It is very complicated, but seems like at some stage BufferedWriter is given to PrintStream constructor.

Comment: So, did you understand? What is the point to have print() and do not say that it flushes?

Answer (score 2):

I went step by step using debugger and this is what I found:
[image]
`String s` is displayed in the console after 527th line, so it's before line 528 in which the check of having `\n` is done.

In `charOut.flushBuffer()` deep inside, there is the following method called:[image]

In which, the check about `\n` is missing.

The flow is as it follows:

1. `System.out#print(String s)` calls `PrintStream#print(String s)`.
2. `PrintStream#print(String s)` calls `PrintStream#write(String s)`.
3. `PrintStream#write(String s)` calls `OutputSteamWriter#flushBuffer()`.
4. `OutputStreamWriter#flushBuffer()` calls `StreamEncoder#flushBuffer()`.
5. `StreamEncoder#flushBuffer()` calls `StreamEncoder#implFlushBuffer()`.
6. `StreamEncoder#implFlushBuffer()` calls `StreamEncoder#writeBytes()`.
7. `StreamEncoder#writeBytes()` calls `PrintStream#write(byte buf[], int off, int len)` which flushes the buffor `if(autoFlush)`.

The most important snippets are above. The `BufferedWriter` seems not to be called in this flow.

Comment: That's exactly what the OP is asking about - why is that affecting things in this case?

Comment: API says, that if auto-flush  is set to true, then only println is flushed, not print (!!!). I quote apidoc on PrintStream (its first paragraphs): "Optionally, a PrintStream can be created so as to flush automatically; this means that the flush method is automatically invoked after a byte array is written, one of the println methods is invoked, or a newline character or byte ('\n') is written."

Comment: I also guess maybe its auto-flush is set to true, but could anyone please point to the place where it happens? I cannot find this place so far...

Comment: @LrnBoy I added in deep explanation.

Answer (score 0):

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8025883 describes this bug.

This bit me in a program that reads and parses a binary file, doing a lot of `System.out.printf()` calls, which took way longer that it should.

What I ended up doing was writing a helper class that *violates the contract of Streams* by not honoring every flush request:

```
class ForceBufferedOutputStream extends OutputStream {

    OutputStream out;
    byte[] buffer;
    int buflen;
    boolean haveNewline;
    private static final int bufsize=16384;

    public ForceBufferedOutputStream(OutputStream out) {
        this.out=out;
        this.buffer=new byte[bufsize];
        this.buflen=0;
        this.haveNewline=false;
    }
    @Override
    public void flush() throws IOException {
        if (this.haveNewline || this.buflen==bufsize) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, buflen);
            out.flush();
            this.buflen=0;
            this.haveNewline=false;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        out.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void write(int b) throws IOException {
        buffer[buflen++]=(byte)b;
        if (b=='\n')
            this.haveNewline=true;
        if (buflen==bufsize)
            this.flush();
    }
}
```

then using a `new PrintStream(new ForceBufferedOutputStream(System.out))` instead of `System.out`.

I consider this a horrible piece of software - as said, it violates the contract that `flush()` needs to make sure everything is written, and it could optimize array `write` calls. But in my case, runtime was cut from 17 minutes to 3:45, so if you need a copy/paste that speeds up a quick and dirty type of program, I hope it helps somewhat.